# How is an input translated to the input units of a NN

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am quite new to machine learning and neural nets. I‘ve used the following model for sentiment analysis of short texts. I generally understand how signals are computed, all the way to the output layer. Now what I dont understand is how the inputs are found. When the model classifies a word, how is that word translated to the 512 input units? What features of the word does the model assess and how is that decided?

```
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(max_words,), activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))


  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer='adam',
                metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the model classifies a word, how is that word translated to the
> 512 input units?

As you already noticed, before any kind of written information (single words, sentences or whole texts) can be processed by a neural network, it must be *encoded* into a vector representation. This is called an [*embedding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding) or a *representation* and to find suitable embeddings  is subfield of Natural Language Procesessing (NLP) research.

Over the years a number of different representations were published. For single words e.g. [Word2Vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec) in which a neural network has "learned" the embedding based on the semantic similarity of the words. That means words which are similar in context should be close by in the vector space.

The most simple embedding for a sentence would be a [*bag-of-words*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) embedding. This means we count how many different words we have in our corpus of sentences (e.g. `N`) and we transform each sentence into a vector of length `N` where each index of the vector represents a word and the value at the index the number of occurrences of that word in the sentence.

Of course there are many more sophisticated text embeddings.

Comment: So in the case of the bag of words method; How is this vector of length n converted to the specific number of x input units?

Comment: Well, you first have to know the dimension of you data before you can specify the input dimension. But let's say you want to have an input dimension of 512, then there are more flexible approaches where you can define the dimension of the embedding yourself. The BoW example is just the most simple one I chose for illustration purposes.

Comment: For the model above, the data was preprocessed, and only the 3000 most common words were used (See inputsize =maxwords). This makes sense, as this is probably a way to cap the size of the input vector to a length of 3000. i still dont understand why the first layer has 512 units and how that translates

Comment: In your example `max_words` is the input dimension of the first layer (which is 3000) and 512 the output dimension of the first layer. In my comment above I used 512 as example for input dimension which was not connected to your example, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think i understand. So does the input layer have 3000 or   512 units? I always thought the model above has 3 layers with 512, 256 and 2 units. But is the computation of the input vector of 3000 to technically the first layer? So do I have 3 layers with 1. computing 3000 to 512, 2. computing 512 to 256, 3. computing 256 to 2? Is that correct? So the input layer has 3000 units?

Comment: Exactly, your example has 3 layers, the input layer is implicit in the first layer. Don't be confused, the input layer is sometimes also counted as layer.

Comment: One more question: A signal is computed by the sum of input signals x multiplied with their weights y and adding the bias b. I learned that the optimizer function (with the help of the loss function) is adjusting the weights after each training epoch. Does the optimizer also adjust the bias value? If not, how is the bias value set/adjusted?

Comment: Yes, correct. The optimizer also adjusts the bias value. It can be considered a weight as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methods by which you can obtain the vector embedding of a word.

1. Count based methods: PMI, PPMI and SVD
2. Prediction based methods: CBOW and Skip-Gram

The count-based methods create a co-occurrence matrix of words of shape Vocabulary*Vocabulary where each word is represented by some sort of count of co-occurrence in K neighborhood.

The prediction-based models train on a corpus and create a vector embedding basis on how close the context of two words are.